# Adding sets of numbers up to 16

Tags: clojure, permutation

I have some sets of numbers:

```
(#{7 1} #{3 5} #{6 3 2 5} 
 #{0 7 1 8} #{0 4 8} #{7 1 3 5} 
 #{6 2} #{0 3 5 8} #{4 3 5} 
 #{4 6 2} #{0 6 2 8} #{4} #{0 8} 
 #{7 1 6 2} #{7 1 4})
```

I wish to make each set into a four number vector, such that the sum of all the vectors add up to 16 and they can only come from the set of numbers:

```
 #{7 1}   => [1 1 7 7]
 #{4 3 5} => [3 4 4 5]
 #{4}     => [4 4 4 4]
 #{0 8}   => [0 0 8 8]
```

Lastly, the vector has to contain all the numbers in the set. It'll be great to solve this for abitrary vector lengths :)

How would the clojure code be written.

Comment: Looks like logic programming, e.g. Prolog, fits in here. Haven't tried, but I think core.logic should be of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### With small sets and the originally stated output length of 4

This is easily handled with naive search

```
(defn bag-sum [s n] 
  (for [a s, b s, c s, d s 
        :let [v [a b c d]] 
        :when (= n (apply + v))
        :when (= (set v) s)] 
    v))
```

---

```
(take 1 (bag-sum #{7 1} 16)) ;=> ([7 7 1 1])
(take 1 (bag-sum #{3 5} 16)) ;=> ([3 3 5 5])
(take 1 (bag-sum #{4 3 5} 16)) ;=> ([4 4 3 5])
```

---

#### Assuming 16 is fixed and all numbers are non-negative

The search space even without the set constraint is tiny.

```
(require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :refer [partition]])

(count (partitions (repeat 16 1))) ;=> 231
```

So, again a naive solution is very practical. We'll produce solutions of all lengths, which can be further filtered as desired. If there is a zero in the input set, it can pad any solution.

```
(defn bag-sum16 [s] 
  (for [p (partitions (repeat 16 1)) 
        :let [v (mapv (partial apply +) p)]
        :when (= (set v) s)] 
     v))
```

---

First example has 2 solutions - length 4 and length 10.

```
(bag-sum16 #{7 1}) ;=> ([7 7 1 1] [7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1])
(bag-sum16 #{3 5}) ;=> ([5 5 3 3])
(bag-sum16 #{3 4 5}) ;=> ([5 4 4 3])
```

---

#### Using core.logic finite domains to prune the search space with arbitrary but specified domain set `s`, output length `m`, and sum `n`

This is still fairly naive but prunes the search tree when the target sum is exceeded. I am a novice at core.logic, so this is more an opportunity to practice than an attempt at best representation of the problem. This performs worse than the naive solutions above on small spaces, but enables calculation in some medium size cases.

```
(defn bag-sum-logic [s m n]
  (let [m* (- m (count s))
        n* (- n (apply + s))
        nums (vec (repeatedly m* lvar))
        sums (concat [0] (repeatedly (dec m*) lvar) [n*])
        dom (apply fd/domain (sort s))
        rng (fd/interval n*)
        sol (run 1 [q]
              (== q nums) 
              (everyg #(fd/in % dom) nums) 
              (everyg #(fd/in % rng) sums) 
              (everyg #(apply fd/+ %) 
                      (map cons nums (partition 2 1 sums))))] 
    (when (seq sol) (sort (concat s (first sol))))))
```

---

```
(bag-sum-logic #{7 1} 4 16) ;=> (1 1 7 7)
(bag-sum-logic #{7 1} 10 16) ;=> (1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 7)
(bag-sum-logic #{3 5} 4 16) ;=> (3 3 5 5)
(bag-sum-logic #{3 4 5} 4 16) ;=> (3 4 4 5)

(time (bag-sum-logic #{3 4 5} 30 100))
;=> "Elapsed time: 18.739627 msecs"
;=> (3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5)
```

---

#### Better algorithms for the general case?

This problem is a [linear Diophantine equation, which can be solved with the Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewgilbert/Research/GilbertPathria.pdf) via matrix unimodular row reduction, i.e. carry out the Euclidean algorithm in one column while bringing the entire basis row along for the ride.

For example, in the case of #{3 5} and sum 16, you want to solve the equation

```
3x + 5y = 16
```

subject to the additional constraints that `x > 0`, `y > 0` and `x + y = 4` (your example).

The matrix and reduction steps

```
[[3 1 0]  ->  [[3  1 0]   ->  [[1  2 -1]   ->  [[1  2 -1]
 [5 0 1]]      [2 -1 1]]       [2 -1 1]]        [0 -5 3]]
```

So the GCD of 3 and 5 is 1, which divides into 16. Therefore there are (infinitely many) solutions before the constraints

```
x = 16 * 2 - 5k
y = 16 * -1 + 3k
```

Since we need `x + y = 4`, `4 = 16 - 2k` and therefore `k = 6`, so

```
x = 2
y = 2
```

And we need 2 copies of 3 and 2 copies of 5.

This generalizes to more than 2 variables in the same manner. But whereas for 2 variables the length of the solution fully constrains the single free variable as shown above, more than 3 variables can be underspecified.

Solving linear Diophantine equations can be done in polynomial time. However, once you add the bounds `(0, m)`, finding a solution becomes NP-complete, though a quick perusal of [research](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/2778549_Solving_a_System_of_Linear_Diophantine_Equations_With_Lower_and_Upper_Bounds_on_the_Variables) [results](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11792086_14) suggest there are fairly tractable approaches.

Comment: Nice solution. How would you generalize it to an arbitrary sized vector?

Comment: @KobbyPemson since the execution time of this function grows exponentially with the size of the vector, you probably don't want to extend it to an arbitrary-sized vector.

Comment: @KobbyPemson You could use `selections` from combinatorics, but Alex is right, naive search will not scale well.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was hoping to get it working for arbitrary length vectors. I've added an additional condition as well. Please see update

Answer (score 1):

Working on the assumptions that you only want one solution per set and you want the solution ordered ascending as per your example this is what I came up with. There aren't many combinations of sets of 1-4 numbers so the way I initially decomposed the problem was to look at what the pattern of possible solutions might look like.

```
(def x #{3 5})

(def g 16)

(def y {1 [[0 0 0 0]]
        2 [[0 0 0 1][0 0 1 1][0 1 1 1]]
        3 [[0 0 1 2][0 1 1 2][0 1 2 2]]
        4 [[0 1 2 3]]})
```

This key of this map indicates the size of the set `x` that is being evaluated. The values are the possible permutations of indices to the set once it is sorted into a vector. Now we can choose the permutations based on the size of the set and calculate the values of each permutation, stopping as soon as we reach the goal:

```
(filter #(= g (apply + %))
  (for [p (y (count x))]
    (mapv #((into [] (sort x)) %) p)))
```

The values of each key of the map above the permutations form a pattern: the first index is always 0 and the last always is the set size - 1 and all values are either the same as or one above the value to the left. Therefore, the above map can be generalised to:

```
(defn y2 [m s]
  (map (fn [c] (reduce #(conj %1 (+ %2 (peek %1))) [0] c))
    (clojure.math.combinatorics/permutations
      (mapv #(if (>= % (dec s)) 0 1) (range (dec m))))))

(def y (partial y2 4))
```

The filter will now work for any number of set items up to `s`. As the input set is sorted, the search could be optimised to find the right (or no) solution by doing a binary search over the permutations of possible solutions for log2n search time.

Comment: The last claim about binary search is false. The test vectors will be sorted lexicographically, not by sum. `(map (partial apply +) (for [p (y2 5 3)] (mapv [1 10 100] p))) ;=>  (311 221 131 212 122 113)` is not in order. You've also assumed that at least one of each number in the set must be used, so `#{1 4}` would fail as an input. It is not clear from the problem statement whether this is desired. There is a decent solution in here. It is just a bit hard to follow.

Comment: The assumption around each member of the set having to be used is true but you could just wrap my function in another which `disj`s one or more set members. You're right about the binary search! It looks like I made an assumption about the permutation function that doesn't hold. However it should be possible to generate permutations in such a way that the sums generated are sorted if the input set is also sorted. Having said that, I'm too tired to test that out right now :)

Comment: Once you have to generate all the permutations, you don't gain anything by doing a binary search -- you could have just checked the predicate during generation. This is certainly not log(n) complexity! Indeed if you aren't exceeding careful you'll either have to hold an excessive number of permutations in memory during the binary search or regenerate them multiple times. You would need an efficient way to generate at a given index without having to generate the priors, which is possible for the sequence of permutations in lexicographical order, but probably not feasible ordered by sum.

Comment: It depends on the use case. If the set size doesn't change, you can just generate the permutations of indexes map once resulting in something like my initial hand-crafted map. This could then be reused to do a binary search and the creation time of the permutation map would become irrelevant in this case. It all depends on the specific requirements: Can we exclude any set members? Do we want multiple results? Should the results be sorted? Is the range of set sizes fixed? Do we want to be able to pass different aggregation functions?  Etc